# Postgresql tablespace Objects

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Created a tablespace in postgresql 9.6.1 and created a database with newly created tablespace. Everything is fine at this point.

Any object like tables created in the database are under pg_default. Am I missing something here? Or is this an issue.

```
CREATE USER test PASSWORD '<password>';

CREATE TABLESPACE test_data OWNER test LOCATION '<directory>';

CREATE DATABASE testdb WITH OWNER = test ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = test_data;
```

Comment: Did you change the default tablespace for the database?

Comment: I created the database with new tablespace name.

Comment: And how do you check the table's tablespace?

Comment: Used the pgAdmin4.1 and table properties.`\c testdb` `\l+`

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin but maybe it doesn't show the tablespace for a table if that table is using the default tablespace (similar to the information in `pg_tables`)

Comment: It does show the tablespace name but it is showing as pg_default.      `schemaname     |        tablename        | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity
--------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
 test             | bu_lookup               | test |            | t          | f        | f           | f` pg_tables is not showing the tablespace name. If it is blank is that means it is using default in my case it should test_data

Comment: Correct, `pg_table.tablespace` will be null if the table is using the default tablespace of the database. I wouldn't be surprised if pgAdmin simply uses that value

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in pgAdmin4.1. Bug number 2069.

[pgAdmin Bug 2069](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i1VY.png)

Comment: pgAdmin4 v1.2 has this issue fixed. It is released today.